# c# substring not found although the substring exists

Tags: c#, string, contains, indexof

I have strings which look like

string1 = "~01301~^~DATA1,DATA2 DATA3~^15.87^717^0.85^81.11^2.11^0.06^0"

string2 = "~01341~^~DATA3,DATA2 DATA1 DATA4~^15.87^717^0.85^81.11^2.11^0.06^0"

string3 = "~01347~^~DATA1 DATA2,DATA3~^15.87^717^0.85^81.11^2.11^0.06^0"

and so on.

Out of these strings, I need to find which strings contain let's say "DATA1" substring. In C#, contains - indexOf - lastIndexOf methods cannot find DATA1 in string1 but they all find DATA1 in string2 and string3.

What could be the reason for this? First DATA1 is surrounded with tilde and comma but I guess those shouldn't affect or am I wrong?

EDIT: 
The relevant part of the code is trivial, that's why I didn't post it. But still here is the relevant part of the code:

```
while((line = isoFileReader.ReadLine())!=null)
{
    if (line.IndexOf(input)!=-1)
    {
        matchList.Add(line);
    }
}
```

or

```
while((line = isoFileReader.ReadLine())!=null)
{
    if (line.Contains(input))
    {
        matchList.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code, hard to say otherwise

Comment: could you show the exact code you are using for that lastIndexOf?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using with String.Substring/IndexOf?

Comment: View string1 in your debugger, analyse the characters with much scrutiny and you may discover some hidden characters which you were unable to see.

Comment: Just tested on mine, it works as expected. The bug must be else where in your code. You might need to show some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely an issue when you make the call. string1.Contains("DATA1"); will return true for the string you specified.

Contains is case-sensitive, so perhaps you've accidentally typed the wrong case of one of the letters, or added a space before/after.

Comment: Solved, thanks for the hint. input string had space either at the end or in the beginning. Trimming the input solved, small mistakes are so annoying =)